# Distribute "home" in 2 hard disks

Tags: home-directory, disk

I have 2 hard disks: a SSD and a normal.
I want to install `/` and `/home` on SSD disk and `/home/user/Documents`, `/home/user/Images`, `/home/user/Music` and `/home/user/Videos` on normal disk.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three ways:

- LVM. Use LVM-based partitions so that the home partition "spreads" across both hard disks. I haven't used LVM, so I don't know how to do it, but I do know it is capable of doing it.
- Make partitions on the second hard disk and mount them on `/home/user/Documents` etc. This is what I do now. My `/etc/fstab` contains:

  ```
  #-> sda6
  UUID=... /home/muru/Downloads ntfs-3g   rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0   0
  #-> sda2    
  UUID=... /home/muru/windows ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0   0
  #-> sdb1
  UUID=... /home/muru/devel   ext4    defaults    0   0
  #-> sdb5
  UUID=... /home/muru/downloads   ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0   0
  #-> sdb8
  UUID=... /home/muru/var btrfs   compress,defaults   0   0
  ```

  You'll have to chown the partitions once after you mount them for the first time, but otherwise it's no problem.
- Make partitions on the second disk and set your [XDG variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories) to the mount points of these partitions. Put in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` something like:

  ```
  XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/media/Downloads"
  XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/media/Documents"
  XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/media/Music"
  XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/media/ictures"
  ```